# Just starting making an app, I'm new and stuck in mud

Tags: xcode

I'm reading Nick Kuh's how to book, I'm new to programming. There is a step in his book where you need to create a new folder for resources then a sub directory for images. He wants you to copy image files from the assets folder of the supplied source code into the new image directory. Do I need to purchase the apple developer program to have access to the assets folder? Where do I find this assets folder of the supplied source code?

Answer (score 0):

All source code can be found at this **[download link](http://www.apress.com/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/1291/)** or the **[page I pulled it from](http://www.apress.com/9781430243748)**.

[image: Download Link]